# Geoserver REST Authentication Form

Tags: geoserver

I would like to enable a Login form for Geoserver. This would means that, when a client makes a request using Leaflet or OL3, with an index file etc. The client would be prompted to log in before the layer would load. Any Advice, I have consulted the security of Geoserver but its like i don't understand a thing. 
Geoserver 2.10

Comment: is this for REST access or WMS/WFS etc?

Comment: WMS/WFS for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [enable authentication](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/auth/index.html) on your GeoServer, how you do this depends on how you manage your users and passwords. Once you've done this then the browser will handle logins for you automatically.

Comment: How do i handle this, the could not find a way in the authentication module. Maybe you could help with steps. How do i manage my users and passwords. Thanks. I have spend a week trying to solve this, really need help.

Comment: do you already have a user management system such as ldap or active directory? if not then use basichttp://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/auth/providers.html#username-password-authentication